# How to send commands to terminal window opened from batch file?

Tags: batch-file, terminal

Batch file contains:

```
start "" /B C:\plink.exe -batch user@host -pw passwd
```

Upon batch file execution, a new window opens (unfortunately not minimized, dont understand why) and I want to send commands to this new window from a batch file continuously. How to do this?

Edit:
I want to send "pwd" command from a Batch file to a newly opened Plink window every 10 seconds

Comment: `start` has a `/min` option, if you don't use it, a minimised window is unlikely.

Comment: @ Compo
start "" /B /MIN C:\plink.exe -batch user@host -pw passwd,
does not launch minimised window either. 
This does:
start "" /B /MIN C:\putty.exe user@host -pw passwd